# Address static files in express

Tags: node.js, express

I have this file structure:

```
app
-- app.js
client
-- views
-- source
---- js
------ main.js
---- css
```

I need make access to static file in source with web-address `/src`. Example: `localhost/src/js/main.js`. I use express-static and write in app.js this:

```
app.use(express.static('/src', path.join(__dirname, '../client/source')));
```

But server returned

```
var opts = Object.create(options || null)
                  ^

TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: /home/user/WebstormProjects/project/app/../client/source
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you are using ExpressJS 4.0. It should be:

```
app.use('/src', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/source')));
```

Hope it help.